# Splitting a list in Python and inserting it into Excel

Tags: python, excel, list

I am fairly new to Python here and I have a little challenge. I currently have a list that goes like this :

```
[
    'Rue des Mélèzes', 36.46629112862116,
    ' ', 63.16043128932904,
    'Rang Saint-André', 50.916698753497634,
    'Avenue de la Sorbonne', 70.59562762879435,
    'Boulevard Jean-Leman', 87.80402184628288
]
```

PS: the third value is empty and needs to stay like this

where basically the first value is a street name, the second is the computed value of that street, and the process keeps going.

I am looking for a way to take this list and insert it into excel, while having 2 separate columns, 1 for the names and 1 for the values. I assume it is possible since they follow a pattern?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['Rue des Mélèzes', 36.46629112862116, ' ', 63.16043128932904, 'Rang Saint-André', 50.916698753497634, 'Avenue de la Sorbonne', 70.59562762879435, 'Boulevard Jean-Leman', 87.80402184628288]

df = pd.DataFrame ()
df['name'] = list1[0::2]
df['value'] = list1[1::2]

df.to_excel('plan1.xlsx', index = False)
```

It produces the following spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you so much. Could you enlighten me as to what do the double slice do [0::2]? I'd like to understand better so I can replicate without having to ask !

Comment: @MaximeCampeau The syntax of slicing lists is list[start:stop:step]. Both lists can be created with the same step (2), varying the start.
Please remember that python is zero-indexed (it starts always from 0).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, you made that very clear. Have a nice day!